# Qt - Display several, selectable lines

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

Im writing a tool that simulates Turing machines.

Here, Ive got a transition table of a such a machine

[image]

When a cell is double-clicked, a little dialog pops up (which is a custom widget, derived from `QFrame`) and should allow editing the contens of a cell. A cell may contain several rules (those `|q2, 3, R|` and such)  and I want that little dialog to show these. The thing is that a user should be able to add and remove rules. At first, I wanted to  use `QLabel`s for that, which is fine with the adding aspect, but how do I remove existing rules? I planned having the user select the rules and click "Remove" but do I make sure the entire rule (`QLabel`) is selected?

Or should I take a completely ddifferennt approach to removing? Like letting every label have an own checkbox?

I would like to keep it as simple as possible. For example, `QTableWidget` is too "fat" for this, I feel like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a QListWidget - this will allow multiple lines, multiple selection, without the cells or horizontal/vertical headers.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html